# RPi LED stops working when max or min brightness

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a code for my school assignment:

> Write a function to change the brightness (pwm) of the led with the press of an input switch. The first press and hold increases the brightness, next press will decrease it.

It works when it is between 0 and 100 but when it hits 0 or 100 it just stops working. Here's the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def main():

    sw = 17
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(sw, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
    pwm_red=GPIO.PWM(2,500)
    pwm_red.start(100)
    bright=0
    state=0
    while 1:
        if swin=GPIO.input(sw)
            if state== 1 and bright !=100: '''I put bright !=100 becuase without it, it would just kick me out of the loop when hits 100'''
                bright=bright+1
                pwm_red.ChangeDutyCycle(bright)
                print(bright)
                while GPIO.input(sw)==1:
                    state=0

            if state ==0 and bright !=0:
                bright=bright-1
                pwm_red.ChangeDutyCycle(bright)
                print(bright)
                while GPIO.input(sw)==1:
                    state=1
```

Can someone help me find the solution? I made multiple versions of this code and they all have this problem. I tried to Google the problem but there was nothing there. I can make it so its never reaches 100 nor 0, but it is not the right solution. I want it to be turned off (when it is 99.999999 it is still on)

Comment: Also, I asked the teacher and he couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm surprised that the current coding works at all. I would change the logic here an check for the button status straight away after the first if inside the event loop.

Try something similar to the following, which I haven't tested

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

def main():

    sw = 17
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(sw, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
    pwm_red=GPIO.PWM(2, 50) # 50 Hz should be fine
    bright=100
    pwm_red.start(bright)
    state=-1

    while True:
        while GPIO.input(sw) 
            while GPIO.input(sw) and (0 <= bright + state <= 100):
                bright += state
                pwm_red.ChangeDutyCycle(bright)
                print(bright)
                sleep(0.1)

            sleep(0.1)

        state *= -1

        # Avoid excessive polling
        while not GPIO.input(sw):
            sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Well your code is a little bit off what I need however, it gave me an idea how I should improve my code. The point of that assignment was to change the brightness on a hold of a button, your code is changing the brightness by its self. I fixed my code, I mean it is a mess but it is working :D

Comment: I'm glad the code above helped. I have changed it a bit after your comment, since I have idenfied a problem with it. Again, I didn't test it as I currently have other stuff on my breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main2():
sw=17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sw, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
pwm_red = GPIO.PWM(2, 50)
pwm_red.start(100)
bright=100
state=-1
while True:
    swin=GPIO.input(sw)
    while swin == False:
        if state == 1 and bright !=100:

            bright+=5
            pwm_red.ChangeDutyCycle(bright)
            print(bright)
            while GPIO.input(sw)==1:
                state *= -1
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if bright == 100:
            state *=-1
            time.sleep(0.3)
        if bright == 0:
            state *=-1

            time.sleep(0.3)
        if state == -1 and bright !=0:
            bright-=5
            pwm_red.ChangeDutyCycle(bright)
            print(bright)

            while GPIO.input(sw)==1:
                state *= -1
            time.sleep(0.1)
```